# cd command in gradle not working

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

The cd command in my Gradle task is not working. Using it to go to another folder.

```
task assembleTask(overwrite: true, type:Exec) {
    commandLine "gradle", "assembleDev"

    doLast {
        commandLine "cd tests"
        commandLine "ls"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Exec` task only runs once. You are setting the `commandLine` property 3 times.

- once in the configuration phase, before the task runs
- twice after the task has run (this will have no effect)

If you want one task to run another, you might do

```
task assembleTask {
   dependsOn assembleDev
   doLast {
       file('tests').listFiles().each { File f ->
          println f.name
       }
   }
}
```

Or perhaps you want a [GradleBuild](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.GradleBuild.html) task, not sure

If you want to run multiple execs in a single task you might want to use `project.exec()` instead of `Exec` task. Eg:

```
task assembleTask {
    doLast {
        exec {
            commandLine 'foo'            
        }
        exec {
            commandLine 'bar'
        }
        exec {
            commandLine 'baz'
        }
    }
}
```